# Android: How to save multiple buttons pressed state in tabhost

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-tabhost, sharedpreferences

I have a tab-host with three activities and in each activity I have 4 buttons.

On each button press I am changing the background drawable resource like this

```
 case R.id.button1:
        if (isclick) {
            b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4hlt);
        } else {
            b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4);
        }
```

So now How can I save the pressed state of each button in all three child activities so that when I move from one activity to the other the button pressed state will be reflected on moving back.
first activity -> all 4 buttons pressed -> go to 2nd activity -> come back to first activity -> all buttons in first activity should be in pressed state

even on home button and back button press also It should work.

I know shared preferences is a good Idea and I went through  related  threads but I didnt get any Idea how to do this.

Any help is always appreciated,Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to have activities in tabs? I thought activity can't be nested.

Comment: @Nikita Beloglazov ,  Yes, we can have activites in tabs

Comment: What happens with current activity when you go to another tab? Is it destroyed?

Comment: @Nikita Beloglazov , In TabActivity when tab changes previous activity get paused. i.e. onPause() method get called

Comment: Do yo have any Idea on how to  save multiple buttons pressed state in tabhost?

Comment: I don't understand why pressed state is gone if activity is resumed and not recreated.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep ids of pressed buttons in shared preferences as you mentioned. You'll store a set of ids for every activity. Something like this:

```
public void onStop() {
     SharedPreferences pref = // getPreferences;
     Set<String> ids = new HashSet<String>();
     for (Button button : buttons) {
         if (button is pressed) {
             ids.add(String.valueOf(button.getId()));
         }
     }
     pref.edit().putStringSet(CURRENT_ACTIVITY_NAME, ids).commit();
}

public void onStart() {
    SharedPreferences pref = // get preferences;
    Set<String> ids = pref.getStringSet(CURRENT_ACTIVITY_NAME, Collections.emptySet<String>());
    for (String id : ids) {
        Button button = findViewById(Integer.parseInt(id));
        set button pressed
    }
}
```

But I still think pressed states should not reset when you switch between tabs because activity aren't recreated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , yes u r right, activities aren't recreated and Even I didnt get the result after trying it for couple of hours. plz see my posted question today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796441/android-shared-preferences-inside-tabhost-not-working/13796712#comment18978699_13796712

Comment: I am new to java and android. could u plz elaborate your answer